# how to alert directions when the wrong cell is chosen? javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and have had a lot of help with this code. I have to make this game for school. The game is simple, you just have to choose the right cell in the table, what i want to do is when the wrong cell is chosen i want it to be able to give a direction such as north or south or east or west, telling the player where the cell is. Though i am unsure as how to do so. Here is my code if you would like to look at it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
 
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }
 
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 0px solid white;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 45%;
            height: 55px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: center;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
 
        table.center {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
 
        .Tableheader {
            border: 0px solid white
        }
 
        .TableCell {
            background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
 
        .button {
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: #dcdcdc;
            border: 1px solid #666;
            color: #000;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
 
        button:hover {
            color: yellow;
        }
 
        .TableCell:hover {
            background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
        }
        body {
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}
    </style>
</head>
 
</body>
<div id="MainMenu">
    <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(event)">
        <ul>
    <h2>Hurkles the Game</h2>
    <p>Type in your name and click start to begin</p>
    <li><input  type='text' name ='text1' id='text1'/></li>
    <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' value="Submit" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
 <div id="Table">
<div id='playerName'></div>
<h2>Hurkles</h2>
<p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
<table>
    <table id="tableID" class="center">
        <tr>
            <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
            <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
            <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
            <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
            <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
            <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
            <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
            <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
            <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
            <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
            <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
            <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
            <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
            <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
            <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
            <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
            <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
            <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
            <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
            <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
            <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
            <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="hideAll()">Start</button>
</div>
 
<script>
Table.style.display = "none";
MainMenu.style.display = "block";
var name = '';
function Start(){
    Table.style.display = "block"
    MainMenu.style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('playerName').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;
    
}
var input = document.getElementById("text1");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});
   
function tableText(col) {
  if (typeof event !== 'undefined')
    el = event.srcElement
  el.style.backgroundColor = col
}
    
    
    let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex-1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
    document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => { 
        tableText('green');
        alert("correct");
    }
    
    function hideAll(){
    Table.style.display = "none"
    MainMenu.style.display = "block"
}
function gameReset(){
}
function required(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
    if(empt == ""){
        alert("Please input your name");
    }
        else{
            name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
            Start()
        }
        
    
}
</script>
 
</html>
</script>
```

Comment: You can use sweetalert2 - JS library

Answer (score 0):

I have some observations:

1. You can manage table creation in a more dynamic way (css, events and ids).
2. For "onclick" event, better approach is to manage [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)
   instead of delegating function call to each TD existing in your
   table.

Here is a code snippet you can review and understand the logic per your question:

```js
const tdBuilder = (trElement, tdId, tdClass) => {
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    td.setAttribute('id', tdId);
    td.setAttribute('class', tdClass);
    return td;
};
let table = document.createElement('table');
let span = document.createElement('span');
const prefixRows = 'R';
const prefixCols = 'C'
const separator = '-';
const columns = 10;
const rows = 10;

const winnerTd = (columns, rows) => {
    let colIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    let rowIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    return prefixCols + colIdx + separator + prefixRows + rowIdx;
}
const messageHint = (message) => {
    span.innerText = message;
};
let winner = winnerTd(columns, rows);
let winnerInfoId = winner.split(separator).map((item) => parseInt(item.slice(1)));
//console.info('Winner: '+winner);
const giveHint = (tdClicked) => {
    let hintMessageHolder = document.getElementsByClassName('spanHint')[0];
    if (tdClicked.id == winner) {
        messageHint('Winner');
        tdClicked.classList.remove('cellDefault');
        tdClicked.classList.add('cellWinner');
    } else {
        let tdInfoId = tdClicked.id.split(separator).map((item) => parseInt(item.slice(1)));
        let message = ''
        if (tdInfoId[0] > winnerInfoId[0]) {
            message += 'Left';
        } else if (tdInfoId[0] < winnerInfoId[0]) {
            message += 'Right';
        }
        message += ' - ';
        if (tdInfoId[1] > winnerInfoId[1]) {
            message += 'Up';
        } else if (tdInfoId[1] < winnerInfoId[1]) {
            message += 'Down';
        }
        messageHint(message);
    }
    tdClicked.classList.remove('cellDefault');
    tdClicked.classList.add('cellClicked');
};

for (let trs = 1; trs <= columns; trs++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let tds = 1; tds <= rows; tds++) {
        let tdName = prefixCols + tds + separator + prefixRows + trs;
        tr.appendChild(tdBuilder(tr, tdName, 'cellDefault'));
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}

table.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let tdClicked = event.target;
    if (tdClicked.tagName != 'TD') return;
    giveHint(tdClicked);
});
document.body.appendChild(table);
document.body.appendChild(span);
span.setAttribute('class', 'spanHint');
messageHint('Lets Play!');
```

```css
table td {
  border: 2px solid black;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}

.cellDefault {
    background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);
}

.cellClicked {
    background-color: blue;
}

.cellWinner {
    background-color: green;
}

.spanHint {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```